# Small error within my PHP that I can't find. Unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, forms, error-handling

I am trying to parse a form with this current syntax and I am pretty sure everything is correct for the most part.  I just keep getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/pftech/public_html/wp-content/themes/pureflo/formhandler.php on line 13.  I am really lost here on what this might be and why its causing the whole form to fail. Please any assistance to this matter would be greatly appreciated.  Just lost right now. Thanks!

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Form Handler
 */
?>  
 <?php
    if(isset($_GET['zip'])){
        $sandiego = array('91911', '91914', '91915', '91932', '91942', '91945', '91950', '92014', '92025', '92027', '92029', '92037', '92064', '92065', '92067', '92071', '92075', '92101', '92102', '92103', '92104', '92105', '92106', '92107', '92108', '92109', '92110', '92111', '92113', '92114', '92115', '92116', '92117', '92118', '92119', '92120', '92121', '92122', '92123', '92124', '92126', '92127', '92128', '92129', '92130', '92131', '92132', '92134', '92135', '92139', '92140', '92145', '92147', '92154', '92173', '92562', '92563', '92590', '92591', '92592', '92596');
      if (in_array($_GET['zip'], $sandiego)){
          $urls = array();
            if($_GET["office"] == 1) { 
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/"
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/"
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/"
            } else {
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-delivery-service/"
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/coffee-delivery/"
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-filtration-systems/"
            }
            if($_GET['selection'] < 3 && $_GET['selection'] >= 0) {
                $URL = $urls[$_GET['selection']];
                header("Location: $URL?zip=$_GET[zip]");
            } else header("Location: http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/nationwide/"); 
        } else {
            header("Location: http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/nationwide/");
        }
    }
    exit;
```

Comment: You're not ending the `$urls[]` lines with semi-colons.

Comment: lots of missing `;`'s...

Answer (score 2):

You have no `;` delimiter after every row

Comment: I didn't think you needed to put semi-colons on every line but I guess you do?

Comment: Most likely after every instruction termination, as said here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Answer (score 1):

this code works

```
    <?php
/**
 * Template Name: Form Handler
 */
?>  
 <?php
    if(isset($_GET['zip'])){
        $sandiego = array('91911', '91914', '91915', '91932', '91942', '91945', '91950', '92014', '92025', '92027', '92029', '92037', '92064', '92065', '92067', '92071', '92075', '92101', '92102', '92103', '92104', '92105', '92106', '92107', '92108', '92109', '92110', '92111', '92113', '92114', '92115', '92116', '92117', '92118', '92119', '92120', '92121', '92122', '92123', '92124', '92126', '92127', '92128', '92129', '92130', '92131', '92132', '92134', '92135', '92139', '92140', '92145', '92147', '92154', '92173', '92562', '92563', '92590', '92591', '92592', '92596');
      if (in_array($_GET['zip'], $sandiego)){
          $urls = array();
            if($_GET["office"] == 1) { 
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/";
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/";
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office-delivery/";
            } else {
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-delivery-service/";
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/coffee-delivery/";
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-filtration-systems/";
            }
            if($_GET['selection'] < 3 && $_GET['selection'] >= 0) {
                $URL = $urls[$_GET['selection']];
                header("Location: $URL?zip=$_GET[zip]");
            } else header("Location: http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/nationwide/"); 
        } else {
            header("Location: http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/nationwide/");
        }
    }
    exit;
?>
```

I added `;` this ends a php function

Comment: `;` ends a *line*, not function.

Comment: ; ends a statement, not a line.

Comment: this is true, but when you put data into a variable or array call this a function in PHP ;)

Comment: `function` in php has a very specific meaning, it's basically what most languages would call a `method`. A `statement` is a single operation i.e. declaring a variable, calling a function etc.